# Git checkout tag exisiting branch

Tags: git

There is a tag `1.2` and a branch `exp`.

I can checkout the tag by `git checkout 1.2` and it brings me in the detached head state which is fine. There is already a branch I have created on the server = `exp`. The branch `exp` is based on the `master`. As of now `master` (thus also `exp`) are two commits ahead of `1.2`.

What I would like to do is start at `1.2` and retain all my future commits to the branch `exp`.

However, when I do

```
git checkout 1.2 -b exp
```

I get an error

```
fatal: a branch named 'exp' already exists
```

I understand the logic behind this and I realize the practice is to create a new branch.

What I *essentially want* is to use the existing branch name `exp` and not create a new branch. I don't care about if `exp` is ahead or behind `1.2`

As an example, the following timeline:

- t = 0 --> checked out `1.2`
- t = 1 --> add new code to tag `1.2`. All this new code must sit on the existing branch `exp` because I cannot commit on the tag.

t = 0 is clear for me but t = 1 is not.

Comment: Just checkout the branch.. and then you are _on the branch_ and all subsequent commits will land there.... until you checkout something else. `git checkout exp`.

Comment: I don't understand what "checkout the tag to an existing branch" is meant to do. You *either* check out the tag *or* you check out the branch. What would you want a `git commit` to do in your hypothetical setup. Would that move the branch head *and* the tag? Or something else?

Comment: @Kay: you didn't describe what you *want* to happen. If `exp` and `1.2` point to different commits then yes, checking them out will move to different commits, obviously. But it's usually pretty clear which one you want, so if you want to somehow check out *both* at the same time, then you must have some behaviour in mind that you want to achieve (for example when you commit at that point) and **that** expectation is what I've been asking: describe what you *want to achieve*, and we might be able to point you in the right direction.

Comment: @JoachimSauer Thanks for the feedback. Does it become clear now. Essentially I want to first checkout `1.2` then commit all changes to an existing branch `exp` ; irrespective of it being ahead or behind.

Comment: @Kay: that means you effectively want to re-define `exp` to point to the commit referenced by `1.2`? Then you simply need to use `-B` instead of `-b` (it's a common pattern in git that upper-case flags do the same thing, but turn off some safety checks).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> fatal: a branch named 'exp' already exists

There is a solution to this which is shockingly simple: delete the existing branch.

A branch in git has effectively zero metadata, it's just a name referencing a commit. Committing "on" a branch just points the same name at a new commit. If you want to point that name somewhere else, just discard the old reference and create a new one:

```
git branch -D exp
git checkout 1.2 -b exp
```

Note that the "1.2" here is just standing in for "the commit which is pointed at by the tag 1.2" - what you're really specifying is "point the new branch `exp` at this existing commit".

There are other ways of achieving the same thing; the simplest is to use `git checkout -B` instead of `git checkout -b` [as documented here](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-checkout#Documentation/git-checkout.txt-emgitcheckoutem-b-Bltnew-branchgtltstart-pointgt):

```
git checkout 1.2 -B exp
```

That said, if your git is not too old, you should get used to using `git switch` and `git restore` which are more intuitive commands for various things that `git checkout` and `git reset` do. The equivalent in that case is [`git switch -C` or `git switch --force-create`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-switch#Documentation/git-switch.txt--Cltnew-branchgt):

```
git switch -C exp 1.2
```

Comment: AFAIK `git checout 1.2 -B exp` should effectively do both.

Comment: @JoachimSauer Nice; I've added that to the answer